# How get values after " , " (comma) in php string?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, plugins

Am importing live data from an XML to my live wordpress website. Am using WP-ALL-IMPORT and i have a situation here

I need to import location for my post but my XML gives the coordinates as a single strong ( not longitude and latitude separately) like below

```
<geopoints>55.25424242,25.15498337</geopoints>
```

So how do i remove the value after and before the "," comma with [str_replace]
or is there any other way to do this

Comment: show the code where you import the xml ..

Comment: You can use `explode` to split your string into an array, or `strpos` and `substr` to get the relevant parts of the string

Comment: https://imgur.com/iDSBmZG

Answer (score 0):

if you have the value of geopoint tag

the you can use explode

```
$myGeoPointFromXml = '55.25424242,25.15498337';
$myRes = explode(',', $myGeoPointFromXml ); // this return an array for each value seprated  by comma  
echo  $myRes[0] // show  55.25424242 
echo  $myRes[1] //  show 25.15498337
```

Comment: how will it work in this scenario? https://imgur.com/iDSBmZG

{geopoints[1]} 

is the data string in my xml file

Comment: how you obatin  the xml ?  server  side using php?  or client side using js?  your image is just a part  of you html page code  . .. as asked  above show the code where you import the xml and prepare the page .

Comment: xml is from my CRM generated by them and presented in the form of non styled html

there is no code where i need to import its a plugin and i drag and drop the tag to the field and it calls it to create the data